# I am trying to wrap my Column widget in a SingleChildScrollView but not able to

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to wrap my column widget in a single child scroll view since I am getting overflow. But when I am trying to wrap it, I am receiving errors such as

RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#dc736 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

What can I do to prevent overflow of pixels in my app ? Here is my code:

```
return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Edit your pet`s details'),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(101, 69, 112, 1.0),
          ),
            body: Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget> [
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                              child: TextFieldWidget(
                                controller: _petNameController,
                                helperText: "Pet's Name",
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 50.0),
                        child: Divider(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          thickness: 0.5,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 60.0,),
                          Text(
                            "$_petName is a $_petGender. Update gender",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: GridView.count(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          primary: false,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          children: List.generate(petGenders.length, (index) {
                            return GestureDetector(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  child: Card(
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
                                    color:
                                    selectedIndex == index ? primaryColor : null,
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        petGenders[petKeys[index]],
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 15.0,
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          petKeys[index],
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: selectedIndex == index
                                                  ? Colors.white
                                                  : null,
                                              fontSize: 18.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    widget.pet.gender = petKeys[index];
                                    selectedIndex = index;
                                  });
                                });
                          }),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that your `Column` contains an `Extended` widget, which forces to use the maximum vertical space.
The `SingleScrollChildView` has no limit to vertical space it can use.

The result is that you have a widget that try to take an infinite vertical space.

How can you fix that ?
Either, remove the `Extended` widget, or the `SingleScrollChildView` widget.
Or, you can also wrap your `Extended` widget with another widget with a defined size or constraints like a `Container` with the properties `height` and `width`.

Comment: I wrapped the Expanded widget in a Container with a set height, and wrapped the Column in a SingleChildSrollView. It is working and everything is being displayed on the screen. However, in my console, I am receiving this error: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

Comment: It's probably because your `Expended` widget has a parent (or grand parent, or grand grand parent etc...) which is a `Flexible` or something similar.
Your `Expended` widget serves no purpose if you wrap it with a `Container` with defined sizes.

Comment: What should I do?